# ISC Dhcpv6 pool

Tags: ipv6, isc-dhcp, dhcpv6

I recently set up a dhcpv6 server in my network. The problem is: I set the range of it to

```
#VLAN120
subnet6 2001:470:2249:120::/64 {
        range6 2001:470:2249:120::20 2001:470:2249:120::250;
        option dhcp6.name-servers 2606:4700:4700::1111;
        range6 2001:470:2249:120:: temporary;
}
```

and there is only 1 client in my network that gets the ::250 address. Other clients don't get any addresses at all. What is the problem here?

Comment: In addition: I opened the /var/log/syslog file and I noticed, that 2 clients (2 different clients) have the same DUID. After setting one ubuntu client to DHCP only and restarting the adapter it gets the ::250 address. The other client (with the same DUID) gets the ::250 address for about 5 seconds and then it disappears. The client has then no ip address

Comment: DUID = The DHCP **unique** identifier (DUID) . That's the part to fix.